# Ubuntu does not show a hard drive partion, cannot open it

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem

My ubuntu running on 17.10 is not showing a partition present in my hard drive, the entire partition is missing when I look into 'Files' but shows on Gparted

The 128GB partition that is supposed to show up in files does not.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you may have made an edit of /etc/fstab and removed the mount that occurs at system boot time. Post `sudo blkid` and `sudo cat /etc/fstab` and we can take a look.

Comment: From the [parted documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/set.html) , `diag` flag indicates that a partition can be used as a diagnostics. I would suggest that you remove the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Found a workaround. Open the disks application, click on the partition and press the play button, it immediately gets mounted